# What is meant by 'main' level of NGINX configuration for debug configuration purposes?

Tags: nginx

The NGINX documentation on configuring debug logging refers to a 'main' level of the config e.g. on the following page:

https://docs.nginx.com/nginx/admin-guide/monitoring/debugging/#enabling-debug-logging-in-nginx-configuration

> It is recommended enabling the debugging log on the ”main“ level of
> NGINX configuration to get the full picture of what’s going on.

What exactly is the 'main' section? Within the 'http' block? Right at the top of nginx.conf? Or is inside 'server' enough if you only have a single server block?

Comment: The docs you linked have examples of the usage.

Comment: The `main` context is outside of the `http` context. If an error occurs before Nginx decides that it is processing an http request (for example, when starting up) it will use the definition of error log from the main context. If there isn't one, it will use the [default value](https://nginx.org/en/docs/ngx_core_module.html#error_log).